# How can I intialize an Rc<RefCell<[u8]>> from a &[u8]?

Tags: rust

Note that the slice is unsized. I'm fine with doing a memory allocation/copy, or transferring ownership.

I know that to make simply an `Rc<[u8]>`, I can use `Rc::from(Vec::into_boxed_slice(Vec::from(x)))`, but this approach doesn't work with the added `RefCell`. I note that `RefCell<T>` allows `T: ?Sized`, but it seems like in practice it's hard to actually construct a RefCell containing an unsized type?

Comment: If you do statically know the the length, or it only has a few possibilities you can [go through an array and use unsize coercion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66985fcd7844b067ee675bd898965bba)

Comment: Also no need to go through `Vec<u8>` and `Box<[u8]>`, [`Rc<[u8]>` implements `From<&[u8]>` directly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-From%3C%26%5BT%5D%3E-for-Rc%3C%5BT%5D,+Global%3E).

Answer (score 2):

`RefCell` doesn't use indirection like `Box` or `Rc`, but instead it stores it's data on the stack. Here is a simplified definition of `RefCell` and `UnsafeCell` (both from the `1.70.0` version).

```rust
pub struct RefCell<T: ?Sized> {
    borrow: Cell<BorrowFlag>,
    value: UnsafeCell<T>,
}

#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct UnsafeCell<T: ?Sized> {
    value: T,
}
```

RefCell can hold `T`s that are not `Sized`, but then it itself becomes `!Sized`. There *might* be some way to create `(some indirection) RefCell<[T]>` using `unsafe` code, but I doubt It can be done safely.

The easiest solution, I believe, would be to use `RefCell<Box<[T]>>` instead. `Box` is sized, so when you have it, you can trivially construct `RefCell` containing it. Note, that you have almost written this solution in your question, because `Vec::into_boxed_slice(Vec::from(x))` doesn't return `[T]` (as it is `!Sized`), but rather `Box<[T]>` which you then can store inside `Rc` (or `RefCell`).

As a shorthand you can create `Box<[T]>` using [impl From<&[T]> for Box<[T]>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3C%26%5BT%5D%3E-for-Box%3C%5BT%5D,+Global%3E), and just write `Box::from(slice)`.

To put it all together here's a snippet that you can use.

```rust
let slice: &[i32] = &[];
let boxed: Box<[i32]> = Box::from(slice);
let cell: RefCell<Box<[i32]>> = RefCell::new(boxed);
let cell: Rc<RefCell<Box<[i32]>>> = Rc::new(cell);
```

As a final note remember that when you have `Box<[T]>` you can obtain a `&mut [T]` from it using [DerefMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-DerefMut-for-Box%3CT,+A%3E), so you can change elements of the slice, but you cannot extend or shorten it. To do that you would need a `Vec`.